# Was passing the river the only trial for the soldiers of Talut (Saul)?

Tags: quran, tafseer

In Surah Al-Baqarah, [verses 246 to 252,](https://quran.com/2/246-252) which speak about the story of Talut (Saul), is passing the river (in [verse 249](https://quran.com/2/249)) the only trial?

In tafsir Ibn Katheer it says that the soldiers were initially 80000 (eighty thousand), then 76000 (seventy six thousand) drank from the river, leaving 4000 (four thousand). But in another narration, it says that the number of the remaining soldiers that fought Jalut (Goliath) were the same as the number of soldiers in the Battle of Badr, which I think is 314 or 315.

Does that mean that there was a trial after the river? Allah knows best

Comment: These narrations might be historical and not from prophet s.a.w.w. As i dont think these much details of numbers are described in quran or hadees. I dont see much benefit in finding these numbers out neither do i think we have the mentions of numbers in ahadith.

Comment: Talut and Saul might no necessary be the same person. At least the prophet who came with the miracles that made banu Israeal accept to make Talut a king and Talut are two different persons.